# selecting movie clip inside movie clip

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

how can i select movie clip inside movie clip in acionscript 2 ?? am trying add links to an six movie clip which they are inside an movie clip as flow :

```
var dots:XML = new XML();
dots.ignoreWhite = true;
dots.load('bigdot.xml');

dots.onLoad = function(success:Boolean){
    if(success){
        xmlNode = this.firstChild;
        url_array = [];
        for(i=0;i<6;i++){  

            url_array[i] = xmlNode.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        }
        var all:MovieClip = attachMovie("test","all",depth);

        trace(url_array);
    }else{
        trace("Could not load XML");
    }
};
```

as you see after craete the 'root' movie clip

```
var all:MovieClip = attachMovie("test","all",depth);
```

which contain the other movie clip i need to crate a new loop

```
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){

    }
```

and assign the link for each movieclip but i dont know how to select the movieclip ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make sure the children of your parent `MovieClip` you want to access all have instance names which are sequentially numbered, you can do something like this:

```
dots.onLoad = function(success:Boolean){
    if(success){

        // attach the MovieClip first and then we can use the reference 
        // to access the child clips when we loop over the XML
        var all:MovieClip = attachMovie("test","all",depth);

        var xmlNode = this.firstChild;
        var url;

        for(i=0;i<6;i++){  

            url = xmlNode.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            // Assumes children have instance names childClip_0 - childClip_5
            trace(all['childClip_' + i]);
        }
    }else{
        trace("Could not load XML");
    }
};
```